# Mock HTTP request and response with request payload

Tags: node.js, http, mocking

I'm using following code to mock HTTP request and response object using [node-mocks-http](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http);

```
   var request  = httpMocks.createRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/test',
        body : "some body",
    });
    var response = httpMocks.createResponse({
        eventEmitter: require('events').EventEmitter,
        req : request
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log(response._getData())
        expect(response._getData()).toEqual("kill me");
        expect(response.statusCode ).toEqual(200);
        expect(response._isEndCalled()).toBe(true);
        done();
    });

    handleReqRes(request,response);
```

But it doesn't trigger any event of request.

```
function handleReqRes(req,res){
    req.on("data", chunk => {
        console.log(chunk);
    });
    req.on("end", () => {
        console.log("end");
    });
    res.end("kill me");
}
```

So for above call it just logs "kill me". It is fine if it works with other mocking library I can switch to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I actually need to emit the event myself at the end

```
request.emit('data', Buffer.from(data));
request.emit('end');
```

I'll update the original plugin to have a method to do this.

Comment: just FYI for other users, I've create the PR to node-mocks-http to achieve this.

Comment: For anyone wondering, this was merged, you can now just use `request.send()` and pass it data. I pass it an object and it's handled as a json body.